Memory issues when using Dask
I have just started using 'dask', and I am running into some memory issues. I would like to share my problem along with a dummy code snippet that illustrates what I’ve done.
My goal is to read a large file containing high-resolution global discharge data and calculate the percentiles for each latitude-longitude cell.
I am using 'dask' to chunk the data. However, I am cannot chunk it in time because I need to calculate the percentiles for the entire time period contained in the 'DataArray'.
After creating a local Dask client, I chunk my 'DataArray' spatially and proceed to calculate the percentile for each chunk. Finally, I attempt to save the calculated percentiles as a 'NetCDF' file. I chose to use 'NetCDF4' for this task instead of 'xarray', as I recall that 'xarray' stores data in memory, while 'NetCDF4' allows for disk writing.
The issue I’m facing is that while running the code, I notice that all my workers collectively consume more than '2GB' of memory, and the input DataArray itself is already '2GB'.
My expectation was that the code would calculate the percentiles for a given chunk, save that chunk to a 'NetCDF file' using the 'writer function' I wrote, and then release that information from memory to make room for the next chunk. However, I think that the code is calculating the percentiles for all chunks before saving them as NetCDF, which may be causing the high memory usage.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance in understanding what might be going wrong. Thank you!
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


def calculate_percentiles(da, percentile):
    return da.quantile(percentile / 100, dim="time", skipna=True)

def write_percentiles_data(
    percentile_da: xr.DataArray,
    save_as: str,
) -> None:
    """
    Save the calculated percentile into a single NetCDF file using NetCDF4.

    Parameters:
    - percentile_da: DataArray of the calculated percentile.
    - save_as: string, name of the NetCDF file that will be saved.
    """
    # Open a new NetCDF file for writing
    with nc.Dataset(save_as, "w", format="NETCDF4") as dst:
        # Define dimensions
        dst.createDimension("lon", percentile_da.sizes["lon"])
        dst.createDimension("lat", percentile_da.sizes["lat"])

        # Create coordinate variables for lon and lat
        longitudes = dst.createVariable("lon", np.float64, "lon")
        latitudes = dst.createVariable("lat", np.float64, "lat")

        # Assign coordinate values
        longitudes[:] = percentile_da.coords["lon"].values
        latitudes[:] = percentile_da.coords["lat"].values

        # Define variable with dimensions (lat and lon)
        percentiles = dst.createVariable("percentile", np.float64, ("lat", "lon"))

        # Assign data directly without transposing, assuming this aligns correctly
        percentiles[:, :] = percentile_da.values  # Use this directly

        # Assign attributes
        percentiles.units = "percentile"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #-------create dummy NetCDFfile
    time_dim = 50
    lat_dim = 1400
    lon_dim = 3600
    # Generate time coordinates: a date range covering 120 hours from '1991-02-01'
    time_coords = pd.date_range("1991-02-01", periods=time_dim, freq="h")
    # Generate latitude and longitude coordinates
    lat_coords = np.linspace(83.95, -55.95, lat_dim)
    lon_coords = np.linspace(-179.9, 179.9, lon_dim)
    # Create random data
    data = np.random.rand(time_dim, lat_dim, lon_dim) * 100
    # Create the DataArray
    da = xr.DataArray(
        data,
        coords=[time_coords, lat_coords, lon_coords],
        dims=["time", "lat", "lon"],
        attrs={"long_name": "routed streamflow", "unit": "m3 s-1"},
    )

    #-------Set up client
    cluster = LocalCluster(
        n_workers=6,
        threads_per_worker=4,
        memory_limit=3 * 1e9,  # in bytes
    )
    client = Client(cluster)

    #------- chunking
    chunks = {"time": -1, "lat": 200, "lon": 200}
    chunked_da = da.chunk(chunks)

    #-------- Calculate percentiles using dask
    percentile = 95  # getting 95th percentile
    percentile_da = calculate_percentiles(chunked_da, percentile)

    #-------- Save percentiles
    event_file_name = f"{percentile}th_percentile.nc"
    write_percentiles_data(
        percentile_da,
        event_file_name,
    )


